# AddEventListener on every links and childs

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

Is it possible to attach a new event to every links of a page recursively? Currently I'm using the following code:

```
var linkHandler = function (e) {
  e = e ||  window.event;
  var element = e.target || e.srcElement;
  console.log("Element clicked, type: "+element.tagName);

  if (element.tagName == 'A') {
    console.log("Catched "+element.href);
    element.href = url(element.href);
  }
};

document.addEventListener("click", linkHandler, true);
```

But it only works if I directly click on a link. For example here, only the click on "Work" of the second link works.

```
<a href="./testLink.html"><strong>Doesn't work</strong></a>
<a href="./testLink.html">Work <strong>Doesn't</strong></a>`
```

Is there another possibility ?

Comment: You need to recursively check `e.parentElement`.

Comment: Thanks I didn't thought about something like this !

Comment: there is shortcut. document.links has list with all <a href> in your DOM

Comment: @KrzysztofSztompka is document.links modified when adding links dynamically ?

Comment: I almost sure that yes. In my angular apps which has dynamic links, they are all visible in document.links. But I dont know what with older browsers versions and maybe there are some special situations. But DOM must be updated

Comment: That way you also has access to images - document.images, forms - document.forms

Comment: Ok, then the next question is: How can I detect changes in this list ? So that I update every url at once and when new links are added.

Comment: YOu can check this event DOMSubtreeModified, but it is not in IE8 and less. Look this link for more details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified